# How to model adsorbate layer on a monolayer graphene surface using ASE

Tags: atomic-simulation-environment

My surface is a monolayer graphene. I want to add a layer of water as adsorbate and the parameters are height = 3.31 Angstroms on top of the slab; Coverage = 24/72; The orientation is: The hydrogen atoms are facing down towards the surface.

When i try to use **acat**, i am getting an error '***IndexError: list index out of range***'. My goal is to get the structure as in the following figure:

[image]

Here one can see the orientation of the H2O molecule on top of the surface (the legs are facing down)

[image]

And this is how i want the layer distribution of H2O on the surface. For every 3 carbon there is one H2O

Could anyone please help?

This is the code i wrote:

```
import ase.io
import ase.build
from ase.visualize import view
from acat.build.adlayer import max_dist_coverage_pattern as mdcp
from acat.settings import site_heights
slab = ase.build.graphene(formula = 'C2',a=2.46,size=(6,6,1))
slab.center(vacuum=21,axis=2)
heights = {k: v+3.31 for k, v in site_heights.items()}
system = mdcp(slab,adsorbate_species='H2O',coverage = 24/72, surface = 'ontop', heights= heights)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have now updated(edited) the question in the topic. I have added the code that i wrote. Is this better understandable?

Comment: I am not familiar with acat, but The error "IndexError: list index out of range" typically occurs when you try to access an element at an index that is outside the valid range of indices for a list or array. In your case, the error is likely caused by accessing an element beyond the range of the site_heights list or array. you should check the site_heights list and ensure that it has enough elements to accommodate the indices you're trying to access. You can print the site_heights list to see its content and length with print(site_heights) and print(len(site_heights))

Comment: ACAT dev here. The error is due to the fact that ACAT doesn't support monolayer surface. It requires at least a 3-layer slab to identify surface adsorption sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround for the problem that I had. It goes like this:

```
import ase.io
import ase.build
from ase.visualize import view
from ase.build import add_adsorbate
slab = ase.build.graphene(formula=‘C2’,a=2.46,size=(6,6,1))
slab.center(vacuum=21,axis=2)
water = ase.build.molecule(‘H2O’)
h = 3.31
x = 0
y = 0
add_adorbate(slab, adsorbate=water,height=h,position(x,y),offset=None,mol_index=0)
view(slab)
```

In the above code, the position of the adsorbate over the surface is controlled by the parameter position(x,y) where x and y values are in Angstroms. The x and y values of an atom in the surface can be seen through:

```
slab.get_positions()
```

The parameter mol_index is the atom in the molecule used for positioning. The Index starts with 0,1,2….

```
water.get_chemical_symbols()
```

In my case it’s O,H,H=(0,1,2)

Overall it is a bit tedious work as I need to place one molecule at a time but it works for now.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Tried this approach. From the first row three atoms are selected and then for each of these, atoms on the opposite are selected along the column

```
import numpy as np
import ase.io
import ase.build
from ase.visualize import view
from ase.build import add_adsorbate
from ase import Atoms

slab = ase.build.graphene(formula='C2',a=2.46,size=(6,6,1))
slab.center()
water = ase.build.molecule('H2O')

h = 3.31


a=slab.positions[:,1].min()
index=[]
for i in range(len(slab)):
    if slab[i].position[1]==a:
        index.append(i)

start_index=index[::2]

for i in start_index:
    x = (slab[i].position[0])
    y = (slab[i].position[1])
    add_adsorbate(slab, adsorbate=water, height=h, position=(x,y), offset=None, mol_index=0)
    
    for j in range(i,len(slab.positions)):
        dist=((slab[j].position[0]-slab[i].position[0])**2+(slab[j].position[1]-slab[i].position[1])**2)**0.5
        if 2.84<dist<2.842:
            x = (slab[j].position[0])
            y = (slab[j].position[1])
            add_adsorbate(slab, adsorbate=water, height=h, position=(x,y), offset=None, mol_index=0)
            i=j
        continue
        
        

view(slab)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you please use sentences instead of sentence fragments?